# Переход по ссылке с анкором

Tags: jquery

Выполняется код:

```
$(location).attr('href','http://site.ru/go#1000' );
```

Должен: открыть эту страницу и там перейти на анкор

Как есть: просто переходит на анкор.

как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После вашей команды попробуйте

```
 location.reload();
```

для обновления страницы.

**UPD**

Можно указать параметр **true**, чтобы страница была перезагружена с сервера http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_reload.asp

**UPD2**

Для перехода к анкору без перезагрузки используйте

```
location.replace(ТУТ URL#АНКОР);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Comment: хитро, может всё-таки какой-то другой параметр подставить нужно вместо href? не может же быть чтобы такой возможности не было

Comment: релоад мне не нравится тем, что он перезагружает страницу и видно явно, что она загружается дольше, чем если сделать простой переход

Comment: @Rufex, вы же сами сказали что вам нужна загрузка в вопрос?

Comment: @Rufex, используйте `location.replace()` для простого перехода без загрузки http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp

Comment: верно, но нужно именно перейти по **ссылке** с анкором, а не перезагружать страницу

Comment: location.replace просто перекидывает на анкор, нужно сделать переход

Comment: @Rufex, выразите свою мысль яснее в вопросе. Вам почему-то ни то, ни другое не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте нативный JS

```
window.location = 'http://site.ru/go#1000';
```

Comment: на хэш просто перебрасывает

Comment: @Rufex браузеры вправе не перезагружать страницу, если ресурс не меняется, а добавляется только хеш. А зачем вам страницу перезагружать для хеша? Тогда юзайте `location.reload();`

Comment: @korytoff, автору видимо надо то, что в природе не существует, судя по комментариям к моему ответу.